# Wait for all screenshot before generating pdf in NodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, async-await

My code is generating screenshot in a loop with:

```
function makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename) {
    axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
    (async () => { // Make screenshot
        console.log(url);
        await new Pageres({delay: 2, filename: filename})
            .src(url, ['1300x650'], {crop: true})
            .dest("public/images/" + operation.data.name + "/" + meterId
            )
            .run();
        console.log('Finished generating report for:' + meterId + ' !');
    })();
}



function main(){
  for (const meter of meters) {
     makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename);
  }
}
```

What I would like is to generate a pdf after all screenshot have been generated, like I have seen [here](https://dev.to/paulasantamaria/refactoring-node-js-part-1-42fe):

```
const firstOperation = myAsyncFunction();
const secondOperation = myAsyncFunction2('test');
const thirdOperation = myAsyncFunction3(5);

await Promise.all([ firstOperation, secondOperation, thirdOperation ]);
```

But when I can't find a way to make `makePngScreenshot` return a promise so I can add it to an array, and `await` with `Promise.all`:

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [async/await](https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/) you can use the **async** keyword to make your function return a Promise by default:

```
async function makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename) {
        axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
        (async () => { // Make screenshot
            console.log(url);
            await new Pageres({delay: 2, filename: filename})
                .src(url, ['1300x650'], {crop: true})
                .dest("public/images/" + operation.data.name + "/" + meterId
                )
                .run();
            console.log('Finished generating report for:' + meterId + ' !');
        })();
    }
```

makePngScreenshot will now return a Promise object .

And then you can use **await** to wait for the result of the function,
either one by one:

```
async function main(){
  for (const meter of meters) {
     await makePngScreenshot(url, meter.meterId, meter.filename);
  }
}
```

(I assumed that the meter object has the meterId and filename, it is not clear in your code.)

or with Promise.all:

```
let promises = [];
async function main(){
  for (const meter of meters) {
     promises.push(makePngScreenshot(url, meter.meterId, meter.filename));
  }
 await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Test with:

```
main()
console.log("promises resolved");
```

For more in-depth explanation visit the link i posted, MDN(Mozilla Developer Newtork), or other sources.

Comment: The first method is not good for me, as it will wait 5 second for each one to complete, so whole loop will need a lot of time. I just tested the second way, add a console.log() after Promise.all, but it is not waiting for the screenshot to be generated.

Comment: There where typos in the functions, await keywords was used without the function being async, it is a syntax error so it won't even run like that.